# How can I select mp3 files by album?

Tags: command-line, find, mp3

Sorry, I'm a little newer to Ubuntu.

I want to use the terminal to delete a large number of mp3 files, but only the ones in a certain album while leaving files in other albums untouched. I have too many files to go through by hand in a reasonable amount of time, so is there any way to selectively delete mp3's by their album tag from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

yes.

create a script with these steps:

- `find` all mp3 files in given directory
- for each file check the metadata (`id3tag` can help you)
- if it contains your specific string, append to a list (array, file, you choose)
- at the end of the script, `rm` all files in the list